# specify dynamic array indexes programmatically

Tags: r

I'd like to generalize this code to handle an array of any number of dimensions but I'm not sure how to specify array indexes programatically.  I think its possible with some combination of paste eval substitute quote but I can't figure it out.

```
x <- array(runif(1000),dim=c(10,10,10))
w <- vector("list")

for (i in seq(dim(x)[1]))
{
    w[i] <- list(which(x[i,,] == max(x[i,,]),arr.ind=TRUE))
}

for (i in seq(dim(x)[1]))
{
    # looking for something like:
    # s <- paste(i,",",paste(w[[i]],collapse=","),sep="")
    # v <- x[s]
    v <- x[i,w[[i]][[1]],w[[i]][[2]]]
    print(paste("the max at index",i,"is",round(v,4)),quote=FALSE)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

nvm, figured out how to do it

```
x <- array(runif(1000),dim=c(10,10,10))
w <- vector("list")

for (i in seq(dim(x)[1]))
{
    w[i] <- list(which(x[i,,] == max(x[i,,]),arr.ind=TRUE))
}

for (i in seq(dim(x)[1]))
{
    v <- do.call(`[`,c(list(x,i),w[[i]]))
    print(paste("the max at index",i,"is",round(v,4)),quote=FALSE)
}
```